# How to configure Phoenix Framework behind Apache

Tags: apache2, elixir, phoenix-framework, mod-proxy

I'm trying out Phoenix and for reasons beyond my control, I need it to be served through apache2.

There's a [guide for serving Phoenix behind a proxy webserver](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/serving-your-application-behind-a-proxy) but it only gives an example configuration for nginx (which I would be using if I could).

So I went to the documentation for [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) and added these two lines to my VirtualHost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
ProxyPass /back http://www.example.com:4000 timeout=10
...
</VirtualHost>
```

I have the default Phoenix app running in development mode on port 4000. I tried going to https://example.com/back and the result is

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

I've checked my logs at /var/log/apache2/error.log and there is no error message corresponding to GET /back, although there IS a corresponding entry in access.log. All of the other things I'm serving are still working fine. I'm at a loss here, any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was twofold.

Firstly, proxy submodules needed to be enabled.

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_http && sudo service apache2 restart
```

What led me to this fix was enabling a higher log level in apache2.conf:

```
LogLevel debug proxy:trace4
```

The relevant error was AH01144 ([list of apache2 errors](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ListOfErrors)).

Secondly, I needed a *reverse proxy*:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
ProxyPass /back http://www.example.com:4000 timeout=10
ProxyPassReverse /back http://www.example.com:4000 timeout=10
...
</VirtualHost>
```